# nopCommerce 3.90 HtmlHelper does not definition in admin views

Tags: nopcommerce-3.90

I'm using **nopCommerce 3.90** version. I downloaded yet and not change any code or settings.
I'm looking code base but when I looked admin views pages(Nop.Admin->Views->*), I saw an error
(no error nop.web views)
like below picture link

https://prnt.sc/vdw1ac

Please help me,
Best regards

Comment: I solved the problem as following

Nop.Admin project doesn't has bin folders because admin project located in Nop.Web project

When I copied bin folder in Nop.Web to Nop.Admin, problem is solved

Answer (score 0):

Please check with asp.net core installation in your system, if it is not updated these error occurs check with the version required to run nocommerce and install it will work.

Comment: Thanks Shaikh Mubeen, I solved and commented above.